# Java: How do I fix this NPE?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

So I'm using the collection design pattern and am working with an array list. Whenever I try to add something to the array list, I get a NPE. I probably implemented the collection incorrectly, thus the NPE.

I don't want to copy my entire code as it is entirely too long, so I am trying to give you all a SSCCE. I don't think the contents of ObjectA.java and Objects.java are necessary because I did not get any NPE before implementing the collection pattern.
Special Note: I cannot import Java's iterator.

```
//Game.java
public class Game {
    private World w;

    public Game() {
        w = new World();
        w.getList().add(new ObjectA()); //NPE here
    }
}

//World.java
public class World {
    private Collection list;

    public Collection getList() {
         return list;
    }
}

//Collection.java //I don't know what could cause the NPE so I show everything
public class Collection{
    private ArrayList<Objects> collection = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public Objects get(int i) {
        return collection.get(i);
    }
    public Objects remove(int i){
        return collection.get(i);
    }
    public int size() {
        return collection.size();
    }
    public void add(Objects o) {
        collection.add(o);
    }
    public Iterator getIterator() {
        return new CollectionIterator();
    }

    public class CollectionIterator {
       private int index;

       public CollectionIterator() {
           index--;
       }
       public boolean hasNext() {
           if (collection.size() <= 0 || currElementIndex == collection.size() - 1) return false;
           return true;
       }
       public Object getNext() {
           index++;
           return collection.get(index);
       }
       public void remove() {
           collection.remove(index);
           index--;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the list in `World` class has not been initialized.

```
private Collection list; // Not yet initialized
```

and thus, the `w.getList()` returns an uninitialized list which throws a NPE when you call `add()` on it.

You need to initialize your list before using it.

```
private Collection list =  new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `World.list` is not initialized. Change the world class as given below:

```
public class World {
    private final Collection list = new ArrayList();

    public Collection getList() {
         return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared but never initialized your list in `World` class:

```
private Collection list;
```

Try replacing this with:

```
private Collection list = new Collection();
```